# How to ask for extra permission from my current facebook app users?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am using this code to ask users for permission for my app

```
 $app_id = "1231654321654121";
 $canvas_page = "http://apps.facebook.com/manydldotnet/";
 $auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page) . "&scope=email,read_stream";

 $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

 list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

 $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

 if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
        echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
 }
```

but now i need to ask the CURRENT users for "publish_stream" permission,
I added the "publish_stream" permission to the scope parameter but it is not working for the users already gave the app a permission before.

so how can i fix this?

thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously once the user authorize your app, the `user_id` will always be present in the `signed_request`. So you need to retrieve the user's permissions and check against that.

Here's an example:

```
<?php
$app_id = "APP_ID";
$app_secret = "APP_SECRET";
$canvas_page = "http://apps.facebook.com/appnamespace/";
$GRAPH_URL = "https://graph.facebook.com/";
$scope = "publish_stream,email";
$auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page) . "&scope=" . $scope;

$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

$data = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST["signed_request"], $app_secret);

if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
    exit;
}

$permissions = json_decode(file_get_contents($GRAPH_URL . "me/permissions?access_token=" . $data["oauth_token"]), TRUE);
if( array_key_exists('publish_stream', $permissions['data'][0]) ) {
    // Permission is granted!
    // Do the related task
    echo "You granted the publish_stream permission to my app!";
} else {
    // We don't have the permission
    // Alert the user or ask for the permission!
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
}
function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);

    // decode the data
    $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
    $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

    if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
        error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
        return null;
    }

    // check sig
    $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
    if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
        error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
        return null;
    }

    return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
    return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}
?>
```

More can be found on my tutorial: [How to: Check if User Has Certian Permission – Facebook API](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-check-if-user-has-certian-permission-facebook-api/22/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure once you add the new permissions you are requesting to your scope, facebook will automatically prompt them again with the app's request access dialog and the user just has to approve them.

Answer (score 0):

```
<fb:login-button scope="create_event">Grant Permissions to create events</fb:login-button>
```

Comment: This is rather terse, please explain what happens.